# Sas base соединить столбцы и колонки

Tags: join, sas

У меня есть 2 таблицы. В первой есть список id ошибки и ее описание. Это справочник.

```
id_mistake    description  
m1            a
m2            b
m3            c
```

Также есть таблица с данными, где все ошибки помечены в отдельных столбцах как 1 и 0.

```
row_num    m1     m2     m3
1          1      0      1
2          0      1      1
3          1      1      0
```

В итоге я хочу получить таблицу, где я получу ошибку из 1-ой таблицы и все номера строчек (+ другие данные) из 2-ой таблицы.

Примерно вот так:

```
mistake    n  
m1         1
m1         3
m2         2
m2         3
m3         1
m3         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Это выполняется с помощью `proc transpose`.

```
proc transpose data=work.fact out=want name=mistake ;
by row_num;
run;
```

В выходной таблице `want` получаем:

```
+---------+---------+------+
| row_num | mistake | COL1 |
+---------+---------+------+
|       1 | m1      |    1 |
|       1 | m2      |    0 |
|       1 | m3      |    1 |
|       2 | m1      |    0 |
|       2 | m2      |    1 |
|       2 | m3      |    1 |
|       3 | m1      |    1 |
|       3 | m2      |    1 |
|       3 | m3      |    0 |
+---------+---------+------+
```

Теперь необходимо отсечь строки для которых нет "пересечения" строки и ошибки.

```
data want(drop=errorexist);
set want(rename=(col1=errorexist row_num=n));
if errorexist;
run;
```

На выходе:

```
+---+---------+
| n | mistake |
+---+---------+
| 1 | m1      |
| 1 | m3      |
| 2 | m2      |
| 2 | m3      |
| 3 | m1      |
| 3 | m2      |
+---+---------+
```